# FFMPEG doesn't convert from m4v files

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, m4v

I am trying to transcode an m4v file from iTunes so I can play it on Windows or XBox.  I am running ffmpeg from Windows.  Is there some -vcodec I need to specify or something I need to install?  Here's the command I'm running and the error I'm getting.

Edit: Complete output

```
ffmpeg version N-60393-g9707b53 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  6 2014 22:07:13 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 63.101 / 52. 63.101
  libavcodec     55. 49.101 / 55. 49.101
  libavformat    55. 30.100 / 55. 30.100
  libavdevice    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
  libavfilter     4.  1.102 /  4.  1.102
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000000000268f620] stream 0, timescale not set
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000000000268f620] Stream #3: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000000000268f620] Stream #4: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000000000268f620] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Video: none (drmi / 0x696D7264), 960x718, 3957 kb/s): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000000000268f620] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Audio: none (drms / 0x736D7264), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), 384 kb/s): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000000000268f620] Could not find codec parameters for stream 3 (Subtitle: none (p608 / 0x38303670), 1280x718, 0 kb/s): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Y:02 The Empty Hearse (HD).m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V 
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: M4V mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2014-01-13 18:51:33
    title           : [...]
    artist          : [...]
    album           : [...]
    genre           : Drama
    track           : 2/8
    disc            : 1/1
    date            : 2014-01-19T08:00:00Z
    description     : [...]
    hd_video        : 1
    network         : PBS
    show            : Sherlock
    episode_id      : 1
    season_number   : 3
    episode_sort    : 2
    media_type      : 10
    synopsis        : [...]
  Duration: 01:26:28.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4505 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (drms / 0x736D7264), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 156 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-13 18:51:33
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: none (drmi / 0x696D7264), 960x718, 3957 kb/s, SAR 4:3 DAR 640:359, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 2500 tbn, 2500 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-13 18:51:33
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: none (drms / 0x736D7264), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), 384 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-13 18:51:33
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: none (p608 / 0x38303670), 1280x718, 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-13 18:51:33
      handler_name    : Apple Closed Caption Media Handler
    Stream #0:4: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc), 640x640 [SAR 300:300 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
File 'Sherlock.wmv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] [buffer @ 0000000005fc5760] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
    Last message repeated 1 times
[buffer @ 0000000005fc5760] Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1.
[graph 0 input from stream 0:1 @ 00000000027d7da0] Error applying options to the filter.
Error opening filters!
```

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Comment: Thanks for having a look.  I've included the complete output.

Comment: Where did this video come from? The 'drmi' and 'drms' codec tags make me think if might be encrypted / DRM-protected.

Comment: Ah.  Makes sense.  Came from my Apple TV.  I wanted it on my XBox too.  Is there a practical way to decrypt it?